# Bpython not working after upgrading to Mavericks

Tags: python, osx-mavericks, bpython

I'm receiving the following error when trying to open bpython in my terminal and I'm not sure how to fix it. I'm new to Python and so I think I may not understand the package system correctly. I'm not sure if there is a conflict from having easy_install and pip both installed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/bpython", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: bpython==0.12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah, I think I can answer this. When we released the last version of `bpython` I got confused in the PyPi web interface and accidentally removed the 0.12 tarball from the index replacing it with 0.13.

Your requirement was to have exactly `bpython==0.12` fetched from the index which was sadly not there (it has been corrected by now).